# Taxonomy Sort as as a dropdown

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

One of my client requirement states they need to sort some field based on taxonomy id. I am very much fine with sorting it based on Id or name in asc or desc order. But client states that they need to have taxonomy name drop down menu. Based on selection of taxonomy name it should get sorted(Seems quite illogical) but still is there some way to achieve same.

Comment: Add a taxonomy term to your views FILTER CRITERIA and  Expose the filter to visitors and select drop down menu...

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this will add as a filter criteria rather I want the same as a sort criteria.

Comment: oh I see now, yeah it's a bit illogical what they want. I'm afraid you need some custom php coding for that.